# findcontrol footertemplate in datagrid asp

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

i want to findcontrol of Footertemplate in DataGrid Asp . But it return null . Can you help me .

```html
<asp:DataGrid ID="dtgDSSP" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnItemDataBound="dtgDSSP_ItemDataBound"
            ShowFooter="true" onselectedindexchanged="dtgDSSP_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <Columns>
 <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Sản Phẩm">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="HidIDSP" runat="server" />
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="dropSanPham" runat="server">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="dropSPAdd" runat="server">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateColumn>
```

Code behind :

```
protected void dtgDSSP_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DropDownList dropAdd;
```

`int footerIndex = dtgDSSP.Controls[0].Controls.Count - 1;
        dropAdd = dtgDSSP.Controls[0].Controls[footerIndex].FindControl("dropSPAdd") as DropDownList;
        if (dropAdd != null)
        {
            dropAdd.DataSource = Constant.dictSanPham;
            dropAdd.DataValueField = "key";
            dropAdd.DataTextField = "value";
            dropAdd.DataBind();
        }
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get Footer dropSPAdd control with below syntex:

```
dtgDSSP.Controls[0].Controls[dtgDSSP.Controls[0].Controls.Count - 1].Controls[0].FindControl("dropSPAdd") as DropDownList
```

**So Check below code**

**Html :-**

```
        <asp:DataGrid ID="dtgDSSP" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnItemDataBound="dtgDSSP_ItemDataBound"
            ShowFooter="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dtgDSSP_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Sản Phẩm">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="HidIDSP" runat="server" />
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="dropSanPham" runat="server">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="dropSPAdd" runat="server">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateColumn>
                 <asp:ButtonColumn Text="Select" CommandName="Select"></asp:ButtonColumn>
            </Columns>
        </asp:DataGrid>
```

**Code Behind:-**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
        System.Data.DataTable dtobj = new System.Data.DataTable();
        dtobj.Columns.Add("Test");
        dtobj.Rows.Add();
        dtobj.Rows[dtobj.Rows.Count - 1]["Test"] = "Testimg";
        dtobj.Rows.Add();
        dtobj.Rows[dtobj.Rows.Count - 1]["Test"] = "Testimg111";
        dtgDSSP.DataSource = dtobj;
        dtgDSSP.DataBind();
      }
    }

    protected void dtgDSSP_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dropAdd = dtgDSSP.Controls[dtgDSSP.Controls.Count - 1].Controls[dtgDSSP.Controls[0].Controls.Count - 1].Controls[0].FindControl("dropSPAdd") as DropDownList;
        if (dropAdd != null)
        {
            dropAdd.DataSource = Constant.dictSanPham;
            dropAdd.DataValueField = "key";
            dropAdd.DataTextField = "value";
            dropAdd.DataBind();
        }

    }

    protected void dtgDSSP_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType  == ListItemType.Footer)
        {
            var dropAdd = e.Item.Controls[0].FindControl("dropSPAdd") as DropDownList;
            if (dropAdd != null)
            {
                dropAdd.DataSource = Constant.dictSanPham;
                dropAdd.DataValueField = "key";
                dropAdd.DataTextField = "value";
                dropAdd.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: i try but it show Error : Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: index

Comment: Can you check are you able dtgDSSP.Controls[0].Controls[dtgDSSP.Controls[0].Controls.Count - 1].Controls.Count return value more then 0 or not?
Because dtgDSSP.Controls[0].Controls[dtgDSSP.Controls[0].Controls.Count - 1] get last row in datagrid and control[0] for that last item get the first column for last row(footer template).
and I am able to get footertemplate with this syantex.

Comment: it return "null" , i use dtgDSSP.Controls[0].Controls[dtgDSSP.Controls[0].Controls.Count - 1].Controls in a event Page_Load , i want to bind data to dropdownlist dropSPAdd

Comment: In this case you need to first apply datasource to datagrid and then bind “dropSPAdd” DropDownList in the ItemDataBound event.
Like : -    
        protected void dtgDSSP_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
        {
 if (e.Item.ItemType  == ListItemType.Footer)
            {
                var obj = e.Item.Controls[0].FindControl("dropSPAdd") as DropDownList;
  //bind datasource
            }
}

Comment: This Worked Succesful . Thanks Pragnesh very much ^^